# Is it possible to inject values in session storage manually for local testing?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I usually work on my local eclipse and local IDEs like Sublime Text and use XAMPP locally to work locally. Since local code doesn't involve authentication and many more stuff, I am wondering if its possible to manually inject the session storage values in my web browser so that I can use that in my local settings without having the need to deploy the code to server where I have access to all sessionStorage values I'm looking for.

For example, I have the following code:

```
    var key = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("loggedInUser"));
    var username = key.displayedValues;
    console.log("Username retrieved below");
    console.log(username);
```

And whenever I run this code locally, since I don't have any values stored in sessionstorage in my webbrowser, I run into issues. For local testing, I always have to hard code values and test which I don't want.

**More clarifications:**

I am wondering if I can add it manually in the browser in some manner so that in my code, I can get the value like this `sessionStorage.getItem("loggedInUser")`. I don't' want to set it first from my code and then access it.

Comment: what is the problem ?? `sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');`

Comment: This will happen from the code. I was wondering if I can add it from browser.

Comment: in Firefox you can directly set your values by F12 >> Stockage and then sessionStorage

Comment: @MisterJojo Thanks. I see different options in Firefox's Storage section.There's Session Storage option as well below Local Storage but how do I add it from browser?

Comment: just "click" on the "+" symbol....

Comment: It's doing anything when I clicked on the symbol. See image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkH3F.png   Thanks !

Comment: oh, come on! -> you have to choose the correct `Session Storage` element(url) first) ! (with blue background on left)

Answer (score 0):

just set it like:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('loggedInUser', {object details of your user})
```